# ¿Por que se suben los archivos de texto vacios al servidor

Tags: php, xampp

, Como estan ? , estoy haciendo un script en PHP para subir un archivo de texto al servidor , lo sube sin mas , pero el problema es a la hora de leer el archivo . Cuando abro el archivo en la carpeta *temp* me aparece vacio el archivo

[image: Archivo vacio]

Codigo PHP :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Uploading...</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Upload file...</h1>
<?php 
 
 if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] > 0)
 {
  echo 'Problem : ';
  switch ($userfile_error)
  {
   case 1 : echo 'File exceeded upload_max_filesize' ; 
    break;
   case 2 : echo 'File exceeded max_file_size';
    break;
   case 3 : echo 'File only partially uploaded';
    break;
   case 4 : echo 'No file uploaded ';
    break ;
  }
 exit;
 }

// ¿Lleva asignado el achivo el tipo MIME correcto ?

if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'text/plain') // Es un texto plano lo que se va a subir ?
{
 echo 'Problem : file is not plain text';
 exit;
}

// coloque el archivo donde desee

$upfile = "C:/xampp/tmp/".$_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Ruta del  archivo subido
 
 echo '<p> Ruta del  del archivo : </p>'.$upfile;
 
 $_FILES['userfile']['temp_name']='C:/xampp/tmp/';
 
 $var = $_FILES['userfile']['temp_name'];
 
 echo '<p> temp_name vale : '.$var.'</p>';

/*if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['temp_name'])) // <- Para asegurarnos de que No es un archivo local
{
 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upfile))
 {
  echo ' Problem : Could not move file to destination directory';
  exit;
 }
}
else
{
 echo '<p>Problem : Possible file upload attack. Filename : </p>';
 echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
 exit;
}*/
 
 echo 'File uploaded successfull<br><br>';
 
 // volver a aplicar a formato a los contenidos del archivo
 
 echo '<p> Tamaño del archivo es : '.filesize($upfile).'</p>';
 
 $fp = fopen($upfile , "r");
 $contents = fread($fp,filesize($upfile));
 fclose($fp);
 
 $contents = strip_tags($contents);
 $fp = fopen($upfile,"w");
 fwrite($fp,$contents);
 fclose($fp);
 
 //mostrar que se ha cargado
 
 echo 'Preview of uploaded file contents:<br /><hr />';
 echo $contents;
 
 echo '<br /><hr />';
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### No está subiendo, se está creando vacío

#### Fue comentado el código que sube el archivo

El bloque de código que comentaste, después de las validaciones iniciales, era el encargado de subir el archivo. Al estar comentado ya no lo hace. Era:

> ```
> /*if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['temp_name']))    
>            // <- Para >asegurarnos de que No es un archivo local
> {
>     if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upfile))
>     {
>         echo ' Problem : Could not move file to destination directory';
>         exit;
>     }
> }
> else
> {
>     echo '<p>Problem : Possible file upload attack. Filename : </p>';
>     echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
>     exit;
> }*/
> ```
>
> **is_uploaded_file($origen)** Valida que el archivo haya sido posteado. [ver is_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-uploaded-file.php)
> **move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino)** Guarda el archivo, que fue subido a la dirección temporal $origen que es asignada por php al cargarlo, en la dirección $destino que es especificada por el código (por quien escribe el código) [ver move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
> Si hubo error de copia (El primer echo) reporta que no se pudo mover.
> Si el archivo no fué subido con el método POST (el segundo echo) reporta que posiblemente hay un ataque. Y no se mueve pues implica riesgos de seguridad.

#### Fue agregado código que crea un archivo tipo-texto vacío

La instruncción `$fp = fopen($upfile , "r");` trata de abrir un archivo que no existe, pues no fue subido, y ningún código valida si fue o no abierto. Acto seguido se cree estar asignando el contenido (del no ser) a la variable `$contents = fread($fp,filesize($upfile));` de modo que dicha variable es inicializada como `$contents = null;`.
Y, el engaño, se abre el archivo para tratar de asignarle en valor que hay en **$contents** y se logra. Por eso muestra que existe y es vacío.
La instrucción `$fp = fopen($upfile,"w");` tiene **modo de escritura "w"** de modo que crea el archivo si no existe. Ver [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php), luego se le asigna contenido nulo y se cierra.

#### Aún sin comentar el bloque citado el archivo no subiría

Imagino que **comentaste el bloque** citado porque la página mostraba como resultado:

> Problem : Possible file upload attack. Filename : El_nombre_del_archivo

Eso ocurre porque un par de líneas antes destrozaste la estructura de validación **asignando un path local** al archivo de origen en la variable superglobal $_FILES que **nunca debe ser modificada** (si no se sabe que se está haciendo **y muy pocos lo saben**) escribiste:

> ```
> $_FILES['userfile']['temp_name']='C:/xampp/tmp/'; // **Terrible Error**
> ```

En consecuencia el llamado `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['temp_name'])` devuelve falso y pasa a mostrar el mensaje de ataque **sin tratar de mover el archivo**.

### No basta con corregir el error: Agujeros de Seguridad

#### Se está admitiendo un nombre inseguro

La asignación de nombre de destino acepta el nombre recogido en el cliente y lo asigna mecánicamente (sin sanear):

> ```
> $upfile = "C:/xampp/tmp/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];  
> // aparentemente conserva el nombre del archivo en el directorio  
> // temporal. ¿ qué tal si fuese ../.htaccess ? o algo similar  
> // EL SITIO QUEDA EN CUCOS
> ```

**No se puede copiar código en la web y ejecutarlo sin saber lo que se hace.** Cuando se suben archivos los nombres a asignar en los paths deben ser controlados desde código. De ser posible deben ser aleatorios y únicos y se almacenan en una base de datos, vinculados con sus nombres originales.

#### La validación de tipo mime admite suplantación

Las líneas usadas para verificar el tipo de archivo, usan la receta típica de los manuales escritos por vendedores de aceite de culebra (culebreros en mi país):

> ```
> if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'text/plain') 
>                 // Es un texto plano lo que se va a subir ?
> {
>     echo 'Problem : file is not plain text';
>     exit;
> }
> ```

Aquí sólo se comprobó que el tipo mime anunciado es 'text/plain'
No se ha comprobado que el tipo del archivo lo sea. De modo que el archivo
puede ser de tipo no deseado o peligroso. Cualquiera podría haberlo cambiado. Hacen falta comprobaciones más fuertes, que no son 100% seguras para establecerlo.

### Ahora una solución decente

#### Comprender el contenido del array `$_FILES['userfile']`

La variable superglobal `$_FILES` contiene la información de los archivos subidos al servidor. En su presentación más simple ([tiene varias](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php)) agrupa como subarrays cuyas claves son los nombres (**atributo name**) de los *elementos input* usados para carga de archivos. Cada subarray tiene la forma:

```
<?php
// formato de presencia simple de un archivo en $_FILES['inputname']
$_FILES['userfile'] = [  // uso el nombre empleado en tu código
    'name' => 'El nombre del archivo que se sube', //puede ser tramposo
    'type' => 'El tipo mime declarado', // no es confiable
    'size' => 'la dimensión en bytes del archivo', // la configuración del servidor la controla
    'error' => 'un entero que codifica el error si lo hay', // [ver][5]
    'temp_name' => 'la dirección temporal del archivo subido',
];
// Nota si el archivo no es movido, es borrado por el colector de basura
// luego de servir la respuesta.
// El único valor que se puede tocar (modificar) es el código de error
// ya que es sensato afectarlo en algunas de las validaciones.
```

#### Validaciones mínimas

Las validaciones a realizar dependen de las necesidades de seguridad (y del conocimiento que tenga el administrador del sitio - o quien haga su software). Pero, hay unas que no pueden dejar de hacerse:

**Verificar la información de error**
Antes de hacer cualquier cosa se debe establecer si hubo o no error durante la transmisión de archivos: `If($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0)` se puede seguir. En otro caso notificar [ver descripciones de códigos de error](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php).

**Verificar que el archivo exista y sea legible**
Se debe establecer que el archivo subido al directorio temporal se pueda leer:

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['userfile']['temp_name'];
if (empty($file) || false === stream_resolve_include_path($file)) {
    echo "El archivo no se puede leer o no existe.";
    $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE;
    // se asigna para validación final
}
```

**Verificar que el tipo mime sea correcto**
La validación de tipos mime es muy importante. Php la ofrece mediante la clase finfo. Pero, se debe tener cuidado porque devuelve valores distintos de los esperados si se usan algunas constantes para algunos tipos de archivo (lo he comprobado para imágenes png y svg) pues ha habido modificaciones en IANA y los navegadores no han ajustado el protocolo.

```
<?php
if(class_exists('finfo', false)) {
    $finfo = finfo_open();
    $filemime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    if($filemime != $_FILES['userfile']['type']){
        echo 'El tipo de archivo no es válido';
        // Yo personalmente nunca pasaría este mensaje
        // si hay un impostor al otro lado no le avisaría
        // haría echo 'Error al copiar el archivo, intente más tarde';
        // y anotaría la IP de origen y el log de tráfico como 
        // sospechosos para verificarlos
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION;
        // En mi caso pasaría
        // $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE;
        // No puedo escribir pero no digo porque no confío
    }
```

**Validación de dimensiones**
La configuración del servidor (en php.ini) se ocupa de que la dimensión no exceda el límite permitido. Pero, recuerdo que en algunas notas sobre seguridad al cargar archivos se recomienda **no permitir dimensión 0** pero, no recuerdo la razón (uno suele no recordar lo que no entiende; ese es mi caso en este punto - sigo la recomendación como un autómata)

```
<?php
if(filesize($file) < 1024){
    echo "No se admiten archivos de tamaño menor que 1K";
    $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE; //nota arriba
}
```

#### Asignar nombre para guardar

Si pasó las validaciones mínimas se puede guardar. Se debe asignar un nombre seguro.

```
<?php
$upfile = 'C:/xampp/files/prefijo-'.sha1_file($file).'txt'; 
// NOTAR el directorio files 
$viejonombre = limpiarNombreDeArchivo($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
// limpiarNombreDeArchivo es algún método que quite del nombre todos
// los caracteres que no sean letras o números del nombre antiguo para 
// poder registrarlo en la bd y usarlo sin crear problemas de seguridad
```

#### Finalmente mover el archivo si todo funcionó

Uso el código que convertiste en comentario con una condición adicional:

```
<?php  
 // recuerda que asignamos $file = $_FILES['userfile']['temp_name']
 if (($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0) && is_uploaded_file($file))    
            // <- Para >asegurarnos de que No es un archivo local
 {
     if (!move_uploaded_file($file, $upfile))
     {
         echo ' Problem : Could not move file to destination directory';
         exit;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     echo '<p>Problem : Possible file upload attack. Filename : </p>';
     echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
     exit;
 }
```

Una observación final el directorio de destino files NUNCA puede tener permisos de ejecución y se deben cambiar los atributos de archivo a sólo lectura después de guardarlos (moverlos).

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta parte

`$contents = strip_tags($contents);
    $fp = fopen($upfile,"w");
    fwrite($fp,$contents);
    fclose($fp);`

por esta otra

`$contents = strip_tags($contents);
    $fp = fopen($upfile,"r+");
    fwrite($fp,$contents);
    fclose($fp);`

Revisa la información de  [http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php]